# Klockwork as automatic check-in test (Jenkins + Git)

Tags: git, jenkins, klocwork

I am using standard *Jenkins-git* hook to detect new changes and trigger CI tests. IFF all tests pass then check-in is accepted. **Is there a way I can use *Klocwork* static analysis results as pass/fail criteria before merging with master branch?**

[Klocwork plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Klocwork+Plugin) is only used to embed results as part of the job properties. I was thinking that if I can convert those results into XML and leverage test analysis and pass/fail criteria provided by [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)?

What is the recommended workflow for Jenkins and Klocwork?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You shouldn't need to use the XML approach at all.

You could make the check-in trigger a Klocwork analysis, perhaps in another Jenkins job, which should run first of all.

When the analysis is done, you can use the Klocwork plugin and define a search query according to the documentation here: https://developer.klocwork.com/documentation/klocwork/en/current/searching-klocwork-static-code-analysis

Your query will return the total amount of issues matching the query, but also the amount of new issues. Define thresholds for when the Jenkins build should fail, and voilà! You're done.

Alternative way:

You could write your own script which communicates with the Klocwork Web API and in this way do more customized requests and evaluation of whether you should pass or fail the check-in.